# How to compile pcsxr as 32bit

Tags: software-installation

I want to compile [pcsxr](http://pcsxr.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) as a 32bit software but I am using a 64 bit system

so can anyone help me with this.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Please explain: 1) _Why_ you want to do this. Do you expect `pcsxr` to run on your system? If your goal is to use it on your system, compile it normally (or use their ppa). 2) What have you tried? Did you read the documentation on the page you linked to? How is it failing?

Comment: I do not have problem compiling it but I want to compile it as a 32 bit because what to use pete's gfx opengl2 32bit plugin

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem if you do it "normally" with the proper flags.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I do not know how to do this and what you meant by flags

Comment: Just pass `--build=i686-pc-linux-gnu` to the `autoconf` script.

Comment: If you do not mined can you specify at what point should I use --build=i686??

here the steps I should take by documentation 

`cd pcsxr/

./autogen.sh

./configure


make


sudo make install`

Comment: when you use autogen just add --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu at the end.

Comment: sadly It still compiles as an 64 bit software